# Problems getting IP address from AP

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I'm having issues getting an IP address from an access point. The access point is an open one, but requires login via a captive portal.

I am using Debian Jessie, and connecting via the terminal. I use i3 and a very minimum screen layout, I spend much of my time in a shell without a window manager so point and click solutions are not requested :)

I have developed my own software, and a script, to auto connect to my wireless hotspot. It works, but sometimes dhclient takes too long, and it won't connect. Also my connection drops out randomly.

Here's my script:

**wifi.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Bring the card down
ifconfig wlan0 down &&

# Change MAC address
macchanger wlan0 -r &&

# Bring the card back up
ifconfig wlan0 up &&

# Connect to access point
echo 'Connecting to AP ...'
iw wlan0 connect "AP_NAME" &&

# Get an IP address
dhclient wlan0 &&

# Log into AP
echo 'Logging into BTFon ...'
btfon myusername@btinternet.com mysecretpassword

# Ping Google
ping -c3 google.com
```

**btfon** is an application I developed in C to log me into the cloud so I can get access to the Internet. This works fine and isn't the cause of the problem. You can view the source code here: https://github.com/UndergroundLabs/BTFon. The script doesn't reach this part in the script though, so it's likely unrelated.

I have checked `dmesg` which doesn't yield any results. I can see I'm associated, and authenticated with the access point. I haven't found any errors.

The problem seems to be happening at `dhclient wlan0`.

I thought maybe `network-manager` was running, but I installed without a desktop environment and installed `xorg` and `i3` after install, so `network-manager` wasn't installed with KDE/Gnome etc.

Not sure what the problem is because it worked fine before I had to reinstall. Last weekend my HDD died and had to reinstall Debian Jessie ... and rewrite my scripts because I lost everything (long story).

Any help on the likely cause of the problem?

Comment: Maybe `iw wlan0 connect` doesn't succeed (although returning 0)? Can you add some debugging information to your script, e.g. listing the AP you are connected to, before running `dhclient wlan0`? Maybe it also just helps to add a sleep here and there. These are just wild guesses because there isn't much information about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dhclient` will return 0 even if it doesn't get a response from a DHCP server and then continue to run in the background. use the `-1` option to force it to try only once and return 2 on failure. Also add `-v` to get some more useful information. Likely causes are you need to give the AP some time before you use `dhclient`. Add a `-timeout` or a `sleep` to your script. Or the lease database is messed up because you're changing MACs. I would add `dhclient -r wlan0` after you brind `wlan0` up.

Comment: You're right. `dhclient` was returning before it was complete. I recall in my last script I had a timeout, but I had to create it again from scratch. `dmesg` was actually returning `wlan0: link becomes ready` but I was missing it when I checked. Thanks for your help.